# Sending big exchanges over netty on camel

Tags: java, netty, apache-camel

I get a TooLongFrameException exception when trying to write large transfers using netty in camel.  I can't really shrink the size of my exchanges without some serious refactoring.

As a workaround, I explicitly specify an ObjectEncoder with a larger estimatedLength.  However, it does not automatically convert the object back to its native form.  I have to call convertBodyTo() on the camel route, which requires knowing beforehand the type of the class.

Here's an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    JndiContext registry=new JndiContext();

    //Workaround #1:  explicitly specify the encoder so we can increase the estinatedLength.
    registry.bind("encoder", new ObjectEncoder(99999999));
    CamelContext context=new DefaultCamelContext(registry);
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {        
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            //This is the receiving end of the large data.
            from("netty:tcp://0.0.0.0:9002?transferExchange=true&encoder=#encoder")
                //At this point the body is a BigEndianHeapChannelBuffer not a String
                .to("log:nettyin?level=INFO")
                .bean(System.out, "println")         

                //Workaround #2:  explicitly convert the body to the expected class.  What do you do if you want several possible classes?
                .convertBodyTo(String.class)

                //Now we have a String as the body.
                .to("log:nettyin.string?level=INFO")
                .bean(System.out, "println");            

            //Use this endpoint to send large data.
            from("direct:start")
                .to("log:start?level=INFO")
                .to("netty:tcp://localhost:9002?transferExchange=true&encoder=#encoder");
        }
    });
    context.start();
    final ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
    String s=org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.repeat("x", 1133461);
    template.sendBody("direct:start", s);                
    context.stop();
}
```

Is there a way to not explicitly call convertBodyTo()?  Also how do I handle generics?  For example convertBodyTo(List.class) does not work for List<String>.  I get an exception like this:

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: org.jboss.netty.buffer.BigEndianHeapChannelBuffer to the required type: java.util.ArrayList with value BigEndianHeapChannelBuffer(ridx=0, widx=422, cap=422)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.mandatoryConvertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:169) ~[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getMandatoryBody(MessageSupport.java:99) ~[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I wonder if we can improve the out of the box camel-netty with transferExchange=true to have larger estimated size or what it takes in Netty to transfer the data without a problem?

Comment: An estimatedLength option would help a lot.  However, to me the bigger problem is the generics.  I now have to wrap a List<String> in some other parent object or I can't use it on the receiving end.  Then, it breaks .split() later down the chain.